# Local objects in heap and Factory pattern

Tags: javascript, object, return, local, factory

These are excerpts from Nicholas Zakas book which im not clear about, please help me understand.

```
function setName(obj) {
obj.name = “Nicholas”;
obj = new Object();
obj.name = “Greg”;
}
var person = new Object();
setName(person);
alert(person.name); //”Nicholas”
```

The local object obj is dead in the heap after function exits ( same when it returns the obj too? )

person and obj are copies or reference to each other as an single object in heap ?

he says "When obj is overwritten inside the function, it becomes a pointer 
to a local object. That local object is destroyed as soon as the function ﬁnishes executing" .

Then , in he explains factory pattern as following :

```
function createPerson(name, age, job){
    var o = new Object();
    o.name = name;
    o.age = age;
    o.job = job;
    o.sayName = function(){
        alert(this.name);
    };    
    return o;
```

since now o is local object ,and he said " That local object is destroyed as soon as the function ﬁnishes executing" . so when functions returns o which is a local object and if i

```
var foo = createPerson(bla,18,student);
```

then foo is a reference to a local object which must be dead by then . Please clarify the concept of "returning local objects in functions "

Sorry for the long post , mods please edit and condense if needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first line of `setName` runs the `obj` reference points to the `person` object that was created outside the function - this object has its name set to `Nicholas`. So at this stage  `obj` is a copy of the reference `person` that was created outside the function.

When the second line of `setName` runs, the local `obj` reference is reassigned to point to a new object, so when `obj.name` is called on the third line it is this new object which has its name changed to `Greg`. The `person` object is unaffected by this change of name.

In the factory function, it is not correct to say that the 'local object is destroyed as soon as the function ﬁnishes ' - the local *reference* to the object is destroyed, but the object itself was created on the heap and still exists. If the factory function did not `return o` on the last line, then this object would be garbage collected because no references to it would exist once the function returned, however `o` is not garbage collected because a reference to it is returned by the function.